# Smooth circular progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am using a circular progressbar which has a countdown timer for 10mins. Progressbar is working fine but it is not smooth.Below is my code for circular progress bar.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar barTimer;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    TextView textTimer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        barTimer = findViewById(R.id.barTimer);

        barTimer.setProgress(100);
       barTimer.setMax(100);
        startTimer(10);

    }

    private void startTimer(final int minuti) {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * minuti * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {

                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 6000;

                barTimer.setProgress((int)seconds);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();

    }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to make the progressbar smooth.

Comment: Your `Tick` interval is 1 second... decrease it... play with thi svalue to find out what is _smooth_

Answer (score 1):

I just Divide progressbar to 1000 parts and call every 100 milisecond so it ll be more smooth

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar barTimer;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    TextView textTimer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        barTimer = findViewById(R.id.barTimer);


       barTimer.setMax(1000);
        startTimer(10);

    }

    private void startTimer(final int minuti) {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * minuti * 1000, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {

                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 600;

                barTimer.setProgress((int)seconds);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();

    }
    }
```